# MySQL selecting a column from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to pull information from a second table (particularly, the `class` column). I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `Tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `class` tinytext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tags`
--

INSERT INTO `tags` (`Tag`, `class`) VALUES
('Arya', 'label-default'),
('bull', 'label-info'),
('Cats', 'label-default'),
('Floki', 'label-default'),
('Overwatch', 'label-info'),
('Ragnar', 'label-default');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tags`
--
ALTER TABLE `tags`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Tag`);


CREATE TABLE `post_tags` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PostID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tagID` tinytext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `post_tags`
--

INSERT INTO `post_tags` (`ID`, `PostID`, `tagID`) VALUES
(1, 27, 'Cats'),
(2, 27, ' Ragnar'),
(3, 27, ' Floki'),
(4, 27, ' Arya');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `post_tags`
--
ALTER TABLE `post_tags`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);
```

### Goal:

```
| Tag    | class
|--------|--------------
| Cats   | label-info
| Ragnar | label-default
| Arya   | label-danger
| Floki  | label-info
```

I've tried using this Query, but only one row is being returned:

```
SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE `Tag` IN 
(SELECT `tagID` FROM `post_tags` WHERE `post_tags`.`PostID` = 27)
```

Comment: There should be two results, unless I fudged up my example. Since I'm selecting `PostID = 27` two rows: foo and bar should be returned, with their classes: asdf and sdfg.

Comment: Exactly two rows, [`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b47774/1).

Comment: The issue is not reproducible with the sample data provided. Can you post some data that demonstrate the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: "but only one row is being returned" - then the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: I see the Fiddle, and I'm baffled as to why PHPMyAdmin isn't returning two rows. Here's some screenshots. http://imgur.com/a/X2rng

Comment: We don't do screenshots. Fix your question to reflect your actual data set, and with a fiddle as above.

Comment: Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a18f72/2) with the exported SQL data, I've also updated the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your actual dataset above the post_tags table contains rows beginning with space character in TagID column: Ragnar, Floki and Arya except Cats. But Tag column of tags table contains these items without beginning space. 
Because of this only the Cats is displayed in the result. So either remove manually spaces from TagID or remove them in SQL query with TRIM function:

```
SELECT a.Tag, a.class FROM tags AS a LEFT JOIN post_tags AS b ON TRIM(b.tagID) = TRIM(a.Tag) WHERE b.PostID = "27"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Using this query (which is very similar to a query I've tried using earlier) also only returns one row when executed within PHPMyAdmin as well as my PHP scripts. However, on the SQL Fiddle, it works fine.

Comment: Check the value in the post_tags. In the code above Ragnar, Floki and Arya begin space character but in tags contains these items without starting space. ('Ragnar', 'label-default') <=> (2, 27, ' Ragnar'),

Comment: Try the following query please: SELECT a.Tag, a.class FROM tags AS a LEFT JOIN post_tags AS b ON TRIM(b.tagID) = TRIM(a.Tag) WHERE b.PostID = "27"

Comment: That works! Could you explain what's going on (as a solution)!?

Answer (score -1):

i thing you have problems with the manes you put to your columns:

but you can running the following script

```
select a.PostID,
       b.Tag,
       b.class
from post_tags a
inner join tags b on a.tagID=b.Tag
where a.PostID=27
```

Comment: Obviously if this were true, no rows would be returned - although I agree that it is very odd to equate a 'tagID' in one table with a 'tag' in another.